# react-native android fontFamily does not take effect

Tags: android, react-native

#### Question 1:

I add a fontFamily to index.android.js's welcome style, but it takes no effect. Does fontFamily actually work on android?

welcome:{
fontSize:20,
fontFamily:'roboto-thin',
textAlign:'center',
margin:10}

#### Question 2:

if fontFamily works on android, is there a way to load custom font from assets? Or is this some feature to be implemented by react-native?

Comment: What about using `sans-serif-thin`?

Comment: yes, "sans-serif-thin" works.

Comment: Good. That's the standard way to use the thin font family. Android does not use the name `roboto` (except in the guidelines). Answering question 2: google it. It's unofficially possible and there are multiple questions about it.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

For Android:
Custom fonts were added with 0.16.0-rc. So you need to have 0.16.0-rc version first and after that you can just download any fonts from the web.

1. Put your font files in projectfolder/android/app/src/main/assets/fonts/font_name.ttf
2. Remember to recompile which is: `react-native run-android`
3. And then you can use `fontFamily: 'font_name'` in your style.

Comment: what if I wanted to apply specific font to my every component of my application globally ?

e.g :- Like in HTML, we write font-family into body tag inorder to get that same base font everywhere, likewise is there any trick for android ?

Comment: @YashVekaria yes - check out react-native-global-props here: https://github.com/Ajackster/react-native-global-props

Comment: @peteclark3 Thank you.

Comment: a version of what ?

Answer (score 41):

Also note the following restrictions for custom Android fonts in react-native:

- fonts must be placed in `android/app/src/main/assets/fonts`
- only `.ttf` files are supported
- The name of the file has to match the `fontFamily` exactly. For instance, if `fontFamily` is `'Source Sans Pro'`,
  the file must be called `Source Sans Pro.ttf` (and NOT `SourceSansPro.ttf`). Any suffixes as mentioned in the following paragraph are automatically removed from the file.
- When the font is in bold and/or italic, it must use on the following suffixes:

  - `_bold` (e.g. `Source Sans Pro_bold.ttf`)
  - `_italic`
  - `_bold_italic`

Comment: Hi. In my plist i have `SourceSansPro-Italic.ttf`, `SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf`, and `SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf`. When i put `Source Sans Pro` inside `fontFamily` (example: `fontFamily: 'Source Sans Pro'`)  works fine. But i can't found the way for call `-Italic` and `-Bold`. I have tried with `Source Sans Pro-Bold`, `Source Sans Pro_Bold` and not works. Can you helpme with this?

Comment: This solution in particular has helped me. I haven't seen this information been present in any other answers. I have had set everything up as was necessary, and was apparently missing proper naming of the font file. Once I have added `_bold_italic` to it, everything worked. FYI, I also had to declare equivalent CSS properties on the style that used that font. @ljzerenHein Thank you for this answer!

Answer (score 8):

Hello this issue waist for me more than two days with "El+Messiri" font "https://fonts.google.com/specimen/El+Messiri"

i was doing every think write  :

1. Put your font files in
   projectfolder/android/app/src/main/assets/fonts/ElMessiri-Regular.ttf
2. Remember to recompile which is: react-native run-android And then
3. you can use fontFamily: 'ElMessiri-Regular' in your style.

   but the  **fault** was that am using  **fontWeight : 'bold'**  after  **fontFamily: 'ElMessiri-Regular'**  and the fontWeight was overiding the fontFamily because "El+Messiri" font has his own fontFamily bold wich is **"ElMessiri-Bold"**

Comment: Such a valuable answer, that solved it for me!

Answer (score 7):

I believe the following is a cleaner alternative to the methods already explained here:

Put all your fonts in you React-Native project directory

```
./assets/fonts/
```

Add the following line in your package.json

```
"rnpm": {
  "assets": ["./assets/fonts"]
}
```

finally run in the terminal from your project directory

```
$ react-native link
```

to use it declare this way in your styles

```
fontFamily: 'your-font-name without extension'
```

If your font is **Raleway-Bold.ttf** then,

```
fontFamily: 'Raleway-Bold'
```

---

Source https://medium.com/@danielskripnik/how-to-add-and-remove-custom-fonts-in-react-native-b2830084b0e4

Comment: Thanks, perfect answer!

Answer (score 1):

This feature has yet to be implemented. See the relevant issue on github [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2919).

Comment: Out of date. Please amend

Answer (score 1):

It seems like custom font was added, check out this commit:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/bfeaa6a4f531cfc18c097bc9ffb6a8dbe3ddc702

Answer (score 1):

### For those facing problems with iOS only - which sometimes does not recognize the fontFamily name correctly:

The only solution that solved my problem was to **log all the fonts to find out correct naming**

(make sure you do the steps below only after adding the assets/fonts and running the `react-native link`):

Anyway, to log them, open the `appName.xcworkspace` file with xcode and then edit AppDelegate.m putting this lines at the end of the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method (and before the return statement):

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
  {
    NSLog(@"%@", family);
    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
    {
      NSLog(@" %@", name);
    }
  }
```

So, when you run the app (from xcode) it outputs something like this:

[image: Output print screen from Xcode logs]

This way, I can use the fontFamily **Barow-Light** or **Zapfino** inside my react-native styles

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I had an incredibly hard time with this, even after following all advice I found.

What worked for me: ensure the font file is named using only lowercase letters and underscores. Re-link. Done.

A lot of hair pulling has been done over this yet it isn't mentioned anywhere as far as I can see.