# Change font of Text item in react-native?

Tags: css, fonts, react-native

I am trying to change font of my title to custom font that I downloaded but it doesn't work I am changin it to anything else it doesn't work, too.

React-native version:

```
"react-native": "0.55.3"
```

Body Part:

```
<Text style={styles.title}>My App!</Text>
```

Css Part:

```
title:{
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 36,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: '30%',
    fontFamily: 'MMA Champ',
}
```

Font Files in Android/../fonts/

```
$ ls android/app/src/main/assets/fonts/
Entypo.ttf       Ionicons.ttf       Octicons.ttf         Zocial.ttf
EvilIcons.ttf    MaterialIcons.ttf  Roboto.ttf
FontAwesome.ttf  mmachamp.otf       Roboto_medium.ttf
Foundation.ttf   mmachamp.ttf       SimpleLineIcons.ttf
```

Comment: Are you using Expo ?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37413939/4363146

Comment: @LouisLecocq No.

Comment: @MohammedFarag doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out later.
I shouldn't have used `fontWeight` with custom fonts.

When I add `fontWeight: 'bold'`, it looks for `MMA champ-bold.ttf` in the file system.

Special thanks to @roach_iam in [React Native Training Slack.](https://reactnativetraining.herokuapp.com/) who helped me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

But you can use custom fonts, 
[Check this post on Medium](https://medium.com/@piyushgupta_81472/using-custom-fonts-in-expo-the-best-way-81f0e785580c)
on how to use a custom font. Knowing how to use will come handy someday like when you get a job in a company that has its own custom font .ttf file